# Is there a way I can join a WP7 and Windows Store app in MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, mvvm, windows-store-apps

The limits by Portable Class Library is killing me, I want easy Access to navigation and WebClient class.
What I've done is I made an Application where the user logs in and sends data back and forth with WebClient. I've done a small test app in WP7 and it works great. I want to build on that knowledge and include a Windows Store app.

So i ditched the PCL, and created a Class Library (.NET 4, since WP7 isnt .NET 4.5). But I cant add a Reference to that Class Library in my Windows Store app, it just states that its unable to add the reference.

So is there a way to use MVVM across Windows Phone 7/8 and Windows Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portable Class Libraries is the best way, but you might wanna consider using the Portable HttpClient instead of WebClient, that should make your life a little easier.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: Wow... life got easy again. Checked out the lib, looks really cool, just what I need, also enables thw await (not the lib, but they made me aware of it). Nice, ty

Comment: Note that you can't create PCL's in the Express versions of Visual Studio :(